# Statements about relations and functions but no restriction on sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

In "Elements of Set Theory" 41p and 44p

> Exercise 3-8. Show that for any set $\mathscr A$: 
> $dom\,\bigcup \mathscr A = \bigcup\{dom\,R\,|\,R\in\mathscr A\}$ 
> $ran\,\bigcup \mathscr A = \bigcup\{ran\,R\,|\,R\in\mathscr A\}$

For this exercise I assumed $\mathscr A$ is a set of sets of ordered pairs. For example, $\{\{<1, 2>, <2, 5>\},\;\{<1, 3>\}\}$. But later I thought it should be included in a proof that if $(\exists X \in \mathscr A \land \exists x \in X \land x$ is not ordered pair$)$ then the equality in the given statement is vacuously true. If this is correct, why does the author let readers consider this possibility?

> The following operations are mostly commonly applied to functions, sometimes are applied to relations, but can actually be defined for arbitrary sets $A$, $F$, and $G$.
> **Definition** 
> (a) The *inverse* of $F$ is the set $F^{-1}=\{<u, v>\,|\,vFu\}$.
> (b) The *composition* of $F$ and $G$ is the set $F\circ G = \{<u, v>\,|\,\exists t(uGt \;\&\; tFv)\}$ 
> (c) ... 
> (d) ...

Here is a similar one, why does the author say "but can actually be defined for arbitrary sets $A$, $F$, and $G$"? When these definitions are applied to a set which is not a relation or a function, they would not have any meaning.

Comment: The def of *domain* (and *range* - see page 40) is stated for a set $R$ whatever; obviously, it is what we expect to be only if $R$ is a *relation*.

Comment: Thus, you have to unwind the def: $x \in \text {dom} \bigcup \mathscr A \leftrightarrow \exists y (\langle x,y \rangle \in \bigcup \mathscr A) \leftrightarrow \exists y \exists X \in \mathscr A(\langle x,y \rangle \in X)$.- Then, "coomute" the existential quantifiers.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks to say "it is what we expect to be only if R is a relation", I understand better now. But what do you mean by "coomute"? It is not found in dictionary.

Comment: Consider the formal def of *domain* and apply it to the set $A = \{ a \}$. Due to the fact that there are no $\langle x,y \rangle \in \{ a \}$, we have the set $\text {dom} (\{ a \}) =\{ x \mid \exists y (\langle x,y \rangle \in \{ a \}) \}= \emptyset$. Thus, also if "useless", we **always** have the set $\text {dom} (X)$.

Comment: Sorry... typo for commute: from $\exists y \exists X$ to $\exists X \exists y$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA $dom\,A(=\{a\}) = \emptyset$ because there is no $y$ such that $\langle x, y\rangle$ in $R$. Is the reason to ask it that you wanted to reiterate "obviously, it is what we expect to be only if R is a relation."?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ok, I now see your edit, I think I have more solid understanding about what I asked. Thank you.